# SSH local to github confusion

Tags: git, github

I'm a total beginner trying my first local to Github. I've properly set up my SSH to work with Github. I can do a

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

and get the success message. However, when I try to initially move my local files to my new Github repo,

```
git remote add origin git@github.com/mygithub/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

I get

```
fatal: 'git@github.com/mygithub/omni.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I try the standard

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/mygithub/myrepo.git
```

it seems to work but asks me for username/password, which then won't take my regular password, but wants a token. Obviously, I'm missing something here on using the no id/pass SSH way. I'm on Ubuntu and working from a command line, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax for a URL / URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (with some simplifications) is:

```
scheme://host/path
```

or:

```
scheme://user@host/path
```

The `scheme` part here is one of `http`, `https`, `ssh`, and so on.  So you can simply write:

```
ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo
```

instead of:

```
ssh://user@github.com/path/to/repo
```

(you must use the user name `git` with the `ssh` scheme because of the way GitHub handles incoming ssh requests).

If you choose to use Git's own shorthand notation:

```
git@github.com:path/to/repo
```

note that there is a colon (`:`) after the `git@github.com` part.  It must not be eliminated.

Comment: Right. Missing the colon. Mistake on tutorial. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong URL. It should be:

```sh
git remote add origin git@github.com:mygithub/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Note that there's a `:` between github.com and your username, not a slash.

Also, make sure that the repository exists before you push it. If you haven't created it on github then you won't be able to push it.